# The setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() of my Project is not working

Tags: java, android

I am developing a small project of test, and I wrote the following code.
I already created in the xml file, a button with id called "registerBtn".

I erased the imports of this source code to shorten space of this source code.

In the java file, I created a variable called mRegisterBtn, in the type of Button.
Inside the method called onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) the mRegisterBtn receives the method called findViewById(R.id.registerBtn);

However, in the mRegisterBtn.setOnClickListener, the part of new View.OnClickListener appears in gray color, and it is not working when trying to test this code.

This image shows what I really mean. Please, perceive that the the part of new View.OnClickListener appears in gray color. It means a error. But trying to compile, this code runs, but the button simply does not work.

Can anyone know how to fix this error, please?

[image]

````
public class Register2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button mRegisterBtn;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register2);

        mRegisterBtn = findViewById(R.id.registerBtn);

        mRegisterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Testing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}```
````

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#007FFF"
    tools:context=".Register">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/registerBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:text="Register"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.499" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried to put a breakpoint as `Toast` could not appear on some smartphones?
Also, there is no problem with the gray color it is just saying that you can remove this and use [Java Lambda Expression](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_lambda.asp)

Comment: I've used your code there is nothing wrong with it. What is the error that you are seeing?

Comment: please,add xml file and error message from logcat or run.

Comment: Shawn, there is no message error.

Thank you very much, Henry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Activity itself as the Context.

If you want a log, then make one

If you want the gray to go away, use a lambda

```
Log.d("REGISTER", "Setting listener");
mRegisterBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    Log.d("REGISTER", "Clicked!");
    Toast.makeText(Register2.this, "Testing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 

But it still doesn't work.

Please can you test?

Comment: Works fine on my end. Make sure `activity_register2.xml` is the correct file you want to load